# Landscape environment in variable position

Tags: tables, floats, landscape

I have a `portrait` document, and I want to put a big table in a `landscape` page. I am currently using the `landscape` environment to achieve that.

As this page is in the middle of the document, I want the previous page to be always full (i.e., there must not be a remaining space between the previous page and the `landscape` page). Is there any way to accomplish this, taking into account the document content changes frequently? I use `pdflatex` to compile the document.

Comment: you could use the `sidewaystable` environment from the rotating package which gives a rotated but floating table.